# Protractor Timeout on prod build

Tags: angular, jasmine, timeout, protractor

I am using the angular seed project. Local protractor e2e-tests against a dev build run successfully, while the same tests against the prod build fail with the error message: "Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 60 seconds."
I am aware of the [protractor timeout documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) and the fix to run asynchronous requests outside of the angular zone. However this does not solve my problem, since my tests runs through against a dev build.

If there any additional information is needed I am happy to provide it.

Comment: How are you running the tests against different builds? Do you have separate conf files for each, or are the prod build tests run on a different machine?

If you could post your conf file(s), that would be helpful.

Comment: I dont necessarily want to post the complete script, but you can have a look at the seed project, where the gulp tasks are defined: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed E.g. I run "npm run e2e.ci.dev": which executes "gulp build.prod --color --env-config dev && gulp build.js.e2e --color && gulp e2e --color". Those are all defined under tools/tasks/seed.